How to interact with an application on a remote computer via tail?
There is a need to send commands to a remote application via tail. Locally I'm currently using tail, I want to control it remotely, but I can't get it to work.
I tried paramiko libraries, I couldn’t install and try python-sshtail. What other options are there?

Managed to tame a paramiko
import paramiko
hostname = '192.168.1.2'
port = 22
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
.......
command = '"Connect:"  > /root/pu/mypipe'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdin.close()

It was necessary to send the command in pipe (/root/pu/mypipe)

What do you mean by "control"? You can't control tail locally, once it starts.

The interface of application allows receiving commands only through pipe. I need to send the Connect command from the local machine to pip on a remote machine

I don't think any of that is related to tail.

perhaps tmux might help here, though I really have no idea what you want to do as sending commands via tail does not seem to make sense to me.

There are multiple options.
ssh username@remote-server-ip 'command-to-run'

this on command line might be the easiest.
You could also use ansible
In python you might want to look into https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner
But since you wrote "tail" it sounds like you are trying to follow logfiles.
For that there are plenty of options like LOKI/Grafana or logstash or graylog

see prev comment
